# What does this phi symbol mean?

Tags: notation

I encountered this symbol in sheet music. Searched the internet and it is nowhere to be found. Closest thing it might be a small letter “phi” but not exactly. [image]

Comment: Please update your post to include the composer, piece, measure number, and instrument. Any of those might help find the answer.

Comment: FWIW, the marking seems to have been invented by Ysaye. An explanation can be found in [this discussion](https://www.violinist.com/discussion/archive/10513), and the table of symbols referred to can be found in the score for the six sonatas op. 27 [on IMSLP](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/b/b0/IMSLP37454-PMLP12909-Ysaie_6_sonates_violon_seul.pdf).

Comment: I'm guessing it's for  a stringed instrument, but without telling us which one, you're not helping!

Comment: @Tim What's doubly odd is that Ysaye's symbol makes no sense placed over a rest, which opens up the possibility that the score displayed is in error to begin with. Weird.

Comment: @Aaron - pure guess - but it may mean play the next E on a different string? (not enough room above said E). Although he had special nomencature for that very occasion...

Comment: @Aaron Actually, I don't think this is the same as Ysaye's symbol, and I don't see this passage among the six sonatas. Ysaye's is more of a "struck-through oval", with the vertical extending above the oval, rather than this more scripty style. I'm not even convinced it has anything to do with Greek phi; the scripty version of that seems to typically connect the "loop" to the vertical on the right but not the left, and lacks the inward curve at the top...

Comment: It's bugging me that I *almost* recognize the passage. And if I had to guess from context, I'd guess that it's an invented and unique symbol to represent a "retake" of the bow; the downbeat would almost certainly have been played downbow, and this symbol could be telling you to move back to a lower part of the bow during the rest.

Comment: The "letter" actually reminds me more of the Greek letter psi (with the "fork tines" joined) than phi.

Comment: @AndyBonner I figured it might be a publisher's variant. But I went through the Sonatas (plus a dozen other scores) as well and didn't find a passage like this one. Hopefully OP updates; I'm really curious.

Comment: False alarm on recognizing it; it was reminding me of the timing and repeated Es in the opening of [Sarasate's *Navarra*](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/9/94/IMSLP307230-PMLP75525-Sarasate_P._Navarra._FS_-_IMSLP.pdf) (at the Allegro), but obviously not; that's 3/8 and uses sixteenth notes. Plus, I think there might be a flat underneath the red circle...

Comment: A web search confirms that there are some fonts that use an almost identical glyph to represent lower-case Greek **phi** (not psi).